# How to find array elements in npm?

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I am trying to find user with the entered email and password from this users dummy array but I get undefined in the return value and hence I am not able to login. If I run this code in console it fetches correct output. Can somebody help why this find function (in the post req) not working in Node?

Dummy array -

```
const users = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Sherry', email:'sherry@gmail.com', password: 1234 },   
            { id: 2, name: 'harry', email:'harry@gmail.com', password: 1234 },
            { id: 3, name: 'cherry', email:'cherry@gmail.com', password: 1234 }
        ]
```

Get Request -

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
        res.send(`<form method='POST' action='/login'>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter pass" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>`);
    })
```

Post Request -

```
app.post('/login', (req,res) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        console.log(email)
        console.log(password)
        console.log(users)
        let user1 = users.find((user) => user.email === email && user.password === password);
        console.log(user1);
    
        if(user1) {
                req.session.userId = user.id
                return res.redirect('/home')
        }
    
        res.redirect('/')
    })
```

**Issue - User1 is undefined.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the `password` value received in `req.body` is a `string` . Your `===` comparator checks also a variables `type`, and `string` and `number` won't match.

##### Option 1

I recommend to change your users data `password` prop to `string`:

```
const users = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Sherry', email:'sherry@gmail.com', password: '1234' },   
  { id: 2, name: 'harry', email:'harry@gmail.com', password: '1234' },
  { id: 3, name: 'cherry', email:'cherry@gmail.com', password: '1234' }
]
```

##### Option 2

If you want to only have numeric passwords you can also change your `find` function to compare numbers correctly:

```js
let user1 = users.find((user) => user.email === email && user.password === parseInt(password));
```

Please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());
```

This two line will make sure you sever-side will receive the data from req.body.
First of all you were sending the data as a form data so you need to include

```
// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

which will allow you to read the data from req.body.

```
    app.post('/login', (req,res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log('req',req.body)
    console.log("email",email)
    console.log("password",password)
    let index = users.findIndex((user) => user.email === email  && user.password == password);
    console.log("index",index)
    let user1= users[index]
    console.log("user1",user1);

    if(user1) {
        console.log("HERE=======================")
            req.session.userId = user1.id
            return res.redirect('/home')
    }

    res.redirect('/')
})
```

Now try the above code snap, hopefull it will help you.